# Unable to save the existing Excel file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, save, export-to-excel

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Dropbox\\Vandit's Folder\\Internship\\Copy of test.xls");
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

    rcount = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    MessageBox.Show(rcount.ToString());
    rcount++;

    if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Both text boxes cannot be empty");
    }

    else if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        worksheet.Cells[rcount, 1] = "";
        worksheet.Cells[rcount, 2] = textBox2.Text;
    }

    else if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        worksheet.Cells[rcount, 1] = textBox1.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[rcount, 2] = "";
    }

    else
    {
        worksheet.Cells[rcount, 1] = textBox1.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[rcount, 2] = textBox2.Text;
    }

    workbook.Save();
    app.ActiveWorkbook.Close();

    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
}
```

This is the code I am using. When I run this code, sometimes it works perfectly and updates fine in Excel. Sometimes it gives me an error saying that "The file already exists. Do you want to replace it?".

Also when I try to open the Excel file normally through the destination folder, it either says that the file is blocked by admin for editing or says that the file is read-only. So am not able to edit anything after the file opens like this as it opens only in the read-only mode in either of the cases.

Also, I am unable to delete the file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quit (close) Excel, and then set the `worksheet`, `workbook` and `app` variables to `Nothing` when you're finished, so they're actually released (closed).

```
workbook.Save()
app.ActiveWorkBook.Close()
app.Quit()

worksheet = Nothing
workbook = Nothing
app = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your prompt reply.

It gives error on typing "Nothing". Also if I replace "Nothing" with "null", it still doesn't solve the problem.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

to try this:

```
xlWorkbook.Save();
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xlApp.Visible = false;
xlWorkbook.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAction.xlSaveChanges, System.Reflection.Missing.V`enter code here`alue, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
xlWorkbook = null;
xlWorksheet = null;
xlApp.Quit();
xlApp = null;
```

i probably went for overkill , but better be safe than sorry